# Are S3 metadata necessary for webpages with meta tags?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, meta-tags

I have an HTML page which includes this `meta` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="public,max-age=2592000" />
```

When uploading this page into an [S3 bucket](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) (for [static website hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)), **is it redundant or still necessary to specify the cache-control meta tag on the S3 Metadata screen?**

S3 Metadata screen:
[image: screenshot of S3 metadata form]
Note that the key/value is the same as the web page's `meta` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A as a general rule, it's better to specify your Cache-Control rules in the headers and not in the HTML meta tags as some proxy servers might ignore the latter.

If you add the Cache-Control rules in the header, it's redundant to also specify them as meta tags in HTML.

Comment: Right. When a browser looks at a response, HTTP headers trump META tags.